# Nth roots subtending right angle at origin

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $\ z_1$ and $\ z_2$ be nth roots of unity which subtend a right angle at the origin. Then n must be of the form(A) 4k + 1(B) 4k + 2(C) 4k + 3(D) 4k

My approach

Let the roots be represented as $Cos \frac{2kπ}{n}$+i$Sin \frac{2kπ}{n}$

At $\ z_1$ the coordinates are ($Cos \frac{2\ k_1 π}{n}$,$Sin \frac{2\ k_1 π}{n}$)

At $\ z_2$ the coordinates are ($Cos \frac{2\ k_2 π}{n}$,$Sin \frac{2\ k_2 π}{n}$)

I tried to use the product to two slope as -1 but not getting the answer

Comment: Can this complex number problem be done by other method

Comment: Easier to use the form $e^{i\theta}$ - what do you know about multiplying and dividing complex numbers in terms of the argument?

Comment: Can you think of any specific $n$ where this happens? Which form does it fit?

Comment: I prefer to convert the number into Argand Plane

Comment: Let put k1 for z1 and k2 for z2 , these are one of the roots that are not consecutive

Comment: You ask whether there is another method. Underneath all methods will be equivalent, but I have put an answer which suggests a different approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let nth root be $z=\exp({2\pi i\frac{k}{n}})$. Now you can say other root of unity is $z'=\exp(2\pi i\frac{k+l}{n})$.

Now a number subtending angle $90^\circ$ anticlockwise from $z$ is $\exp(\frac{\pi i}{2})\cdot z$. So $z' = \exp(\frac{\pi i}{2})\cdot z$

$$\exp\left(2\pi i\frac{k+l}{n}\right) =\exp\left(\frac{\pi i}{2}\right) \exp\left(2\pi i\frac{k}{n}\right)$$

On solving

$$\frac{ 2\pi i(k+l)}{n} = \frac{\pi i}{2} + \frac{2\pi ik}{n}$$

you get $n = 4l$

Comment: It should be D.

Comment: Roots are not consecutive

Comment: @Samar see edit

Answer (score 2):

Here is a hint for a different approach, if you know that the result of dividing one complex number by another gives you a result whose argument is the difference in arguments of the original numbers (counterpart to the fact that multiplying adds arguments). You also need to know that the complex numbers on the unit circle with arguments equal to a right-angle are $\pm i$.

Hint: show that $\cfrac {z_1}{z_2}$ is an $n^{th}$ root of unity (not necessarily primitive).

> Then show that $\cfrac {z_1}{z_2}=\pm i$ and note that both $(\pm i)^4=1$ and $(\pm i)^n=1$

Comment: Much more direct! +1